# This code generates a curve in R. How can I change the color of this curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code generates a curve in R using pwr and ggplot2 packages. How can I change the color of this curve?

```
library(pwr)
library(ggplot2)
P0 = c(0.05,0.06,0.11,0.104,0.16,0.106,0.01,0.1,
0.1,0.1,0.08,0.02)
P1 = c(0.1,0.05,0.12,0.101,0.12,0.105,0.024,0.04,
0.01,0.11,0.04,0.06)
effect.size = ES.w1(P0, P1)  
degrees = length(P0) - 1
pwr.chisq.test(
           w=effect.size, 
           N=NULL,           
           df=degrees, 
           power=0.80,       
           sig.level=0.05)
P.out <- pwr.chisq.test(
            w=effect.size, 
            N=NULL,            
            df=degrees, 
            power=0.80,        
           sig.level=0.05)
plot(P.out)
p <- plot(P.out)
p + theme_classic(base_size = 14)
```

Comment: p + geom_line(color = "green")

Comment: @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz Notice that's slightly different because it's drawing a second line on top of the points (where the original has the points on top of the line)

Comment: Great comments. It worked. @JuanAntonioRoldánDíaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add color info in this way:

```
plot(P.out)+ 
  geom_line(colour="blue")
```

[image]

With the same command you can also use HTML color code, like this:

```
  geom_line(colour="#2E64FE")
```

Answer (score 3):

The color red seems to be hard coded in the `pwr::plot.power.htest` function. However you can edit the ggplot object that's returned in somewhat of a hacky way to get the job done

```
p <- plot(P.out)
p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour <- "blue"
```